# append line of code and datetime in microlog

Tags: android, logging

currently I use like below in microlog.properties file.

```
microlog.formatter.PatternFormatter.pattern=[%d]:[%P] %c - %m %T
```

and getting the result is `Microlog 38623:[INFO]-this is my class.`

I want to get 1) the datetime as `29-10-2012 : 21:55:40` and 2) `append the line of the class` to the log file.

How can I set to the properties file to set both ?

Answer (score 0):

The default time specifier for %d is absolute time. Try to specify how you like to format the time, e.g. `%d{ISO8601}`

Microlog4Android is inspired from Log4j, as such is has support for many of its features. The formatter in Microlog4Android includes many of the patterns found in [PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).

Comment: @kitokid: Did this solve your problems? It would be nice to know.